# Django template: how to randomize order when populating page with objects?

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, django-template-filters

I have a `Survey` and a `Choice` model, and each survey has a number of choices associated with it. When I'm rendering the actual HTML survey page with all the choices, I use the following Django templating code:

```
{% for choice in survey.choice_set.all %}
    <li class="ui-state-default" choice_id={{ choice.id }}>{{ choice.choice_text }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

However, instead of the choices appearing in the same order every time, I'd like them to populate in a random order to reduce any potential bias effect (e.g. someone may be more likely to vote for options that appear first on the list).

If there's a way to do this within the template itself, that'd be great, but it seems more likely that I'd need to do something in the backend in views.py. I've already tried this, to no effect:

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Survey
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ...
        survey = get_object_or_404(Survey, survey_link__iexact=survey_link)
        ...
        if randomize_choice_order:
            survey.choice_set.order_by('?')
        ...
        return context
```

Any idea how I can accomplish this? Maybe I need to instead develop a JS function to randomize the objects after they've already been placed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a custom template tag to shuffle your results.

```
# app/templatetags/shuffle.py
import random
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def shuffle(arg):
    aux = list(arg)[:]
    random.shuffle(aux)
    return aux
```

Then in your template

```
{% load shuffle %}
{% for choice in survey.choice_set.all|shuffle %}
```

Comment: Both `list` and `[:]` create shallow copies here, don't they?

Comment: Yes they do. I'd use `list` to be able to use this filter for iterators that don't support slicing.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! I had to add {% load shuffle %} to the template to make it function.

Comment: love this - even works with `{% with survey.choice_set.all|shuffle as random_results %}`

Comment: Smart solution. But then, for a beginner reading this, you must not forget the empty `__init__.py` file needed in the templatetags directory - this is to ensure the directory is treated as a Python package. Also, in your template file, you would have to add in `{% load shuffle %}`. Finally, if your development server is running, you will need to restart it before you can use the _shuffle_ filter. You can read more on custom template tags and filters [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Comment: @EnockKwesiAddey Hi, well, for python3, u dont need __init__.py file.

Comment: @levi Well, you're right, it works without the `__init__.py` file, but then, the documentation makes mention of adding it. So, I'm thinking it's the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

With Django 1.7+ you can use the `Prefetch` object:

```
survey = get_object_or_404(
    Survey.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('choice', queryset=Choice.objects.order_by('?'),
                 to_attr='random_choices')
    ),
    survey_link__iexact=survey_link
)
```

You can then access the random set with `survey.random_choices`. The original choice set is still available with `survey.choice_set.all()`.

Comment: Very cool -- unfortunately I'm still stuck in 1.6 and afraid of breaking things by upgrading to 1.7.